# Why dows Water in the shower run down glass pane in meanders?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, surface-tension

The last days I noticed that after taking a shower (cabin has glass walls, safety glass if it matters) and finally splashing the glass panes for cleaning soap residues off, some of the remaining water runs down the glass panes in a meander-shaped path like sketched here (sorry for the crippled drawing, the corners should not be there, it's meant to be smooth):

[image]

It seems clear that water on glass has something to do with surface/interface tension. But how exactly can the meanders be explained? Is the surface tension of a curved segment significantly smaller than a straight path? I am not sure if it is at all, because for a torus (as a model for the curved water path) the surface area is
$$A=4\pi^2rR$$
which, when related to the path length $L=2\pi R$, becomes
$$A/L=2\pi r$$
where $r$ is the radius of the cross section of the trickle. So it doesn't matter what the radius $R$ of the curved path is, the surface area per length is always the same (if the "thickness" $r$ does), even for a straight path ($R\to\infty$). But then I'd even say that the longer path of the meander causes larger total area and thus, should be penalized by surface tension.

And this hasn't even mentioned gravity, which should favor the straight path as well...

But maybe it isn't even related to surface tension.

Does anyone know what the heck is happening?

Comment: Well, for one thing the surface it is flowing down isn't perfectly smooth and even nor is it pristine and free or debris and residue. Though I can't say that it would not still meander if it were, though I would think it would be much less. The fluid itself has its own turbulence and eddies at play that could affect things. You would need a finely lapped, polished and cleaned surface to test like a gage block.

Comment: I have no definite answer, but I can tell that any assumption of a homogeneous surface is false. And I always blamed that for this effect without rigorous consideration. I evaluated contact angles on things like glass panes (float, Tin side up and Tin side down) and polished silicon wafers. I found Small differences are common even after treatment with UV/ozone, corona discharge, and atmospheric glow discharge plasma, on samples in the order of 10x10 cm.  I’m certain you don’t plasma clean your shower door ;)

Comment: No, I don't. :-D But I bought a (cheap) ozone generator recently (for a car that was out of order for some time). So I could try that. But then again, I am not even sure that the device generates more ozone than nitrogen oxides... Not a good start for controlled conditions.

Answer (score 2):

A hand waving answer:

The three dimensions we live in are not the same as far as interaction with matter. The vertical because of gravity, for a free drop of water in air would give a straight line track to the ground.

A drop on a surface as in your question will be subject to the gravity force that pulls straight down. **But** due to surface tension etc the motion in the perpendicular direction to the ground, can be considered random, depending on the anomalies of the surface.
Thus the left to right and right to left in you drawing is this randomness opened by the gravitational force into a meandering line.

Comment: Randomness sounds reasonable. Because today I wasn't able to reproduce the pattern. There could be some pretty regular coating on the glass after my wife has used the squeegee, and then the water gets randomly attracted or repelled by that stuff (soap? silicone residues?). We will possibly never know, but anyways, it seems it could be a lot more complicated than I thought at first. The relation of water to its environment is apparently a rich source of surprises...

Comment: Maybe this effect also shares some similarities with gas discharge? Naively one would think that a lightning bolt takes the shortest path. But I guess this is due to MHD, which is not prevalent for a track of water. Or is it? Is there something like dipole MHD? (I know, it's a bit far-fetched...)